# Custom class with Array to deserialize REST API with error No parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, rest

I'm using a Rest API to perform a query where the result is a list of Project and for each project I have the Id and an array of Values.
To Manage this I created a custom Class with int id and array int values.
Then just deserialize the query result to a List of this custom class.
But in the deserialize I'm getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException'
> occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: No parameterless
> constructor defined for this object.

How to do this? What is wrong?

See Code:

```
    using RestSharp;

    public class RemTest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int[] Values { get; set; }
    }
RestClient client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
RestRequest requestInformation = new RestRequest("projects", Method.GET);

typedResponse = client.Execute(requestInformation);
List<RemTest> Test = deserial.Deserialize<List<RemTest>>(typedResponse);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this _exactly_ the definition of your class? Do you have forgot to add a constructor that takes parameters?

Comment: error is obvious, your class has constructor that requires parameters to be passed, create an empty contructor

Comment: For deserialization the Deserializer would need to know parameters if you have constructor with parameters. How can it know these parameters? Right it can't. So it wants a parameterless constructor like this 'public YourClass(){}', that's all.

Comment: Sorry but cannot understand the error message nor your comments...
It says that I have no constructor without parameters, but from what I understand everytime we dont declare a constructor for a class from C# definition a default instance constructor without parameters is automatically provided, so it's not true that parameterless constructor is missing.
Anyway as per the 2 comments above I tried to add the constructor:
public RemTest(){} 
and the error is exactly the same!!
In other way the current class has no construtor that requires parameters and there is no need to have one...

Comment: By other side when I simply instantiate a new object for the class directly there is no error:
RemTest test = new RemTest();
only when this is used in the deserialize...
Using exactly the same class as initially but with a List instead of array gives no error at all!
So where is the error?

Comment: @PaulSinnema
Any clarification?

Comment: Try this: `public RemTest() {}`

Comment: @PaulSinnema you didn't read my previous comment where I stated that already tried that! :(

Comment: Did you find the answer? Is your class exactly the same as the contents of your result? The properties need to line up exactly with casing etc. Show some more code and show the result that is coming from your call.

Comment: No didn't find the answer! Simply changed from Array to List and it works. Will be nice to found the reason behind but seems not possible...